# MySQL ID re-print in the other column not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have following table in my MySQL database with Codeigniter.

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | supplier | user | order_status | transfer_status | status |
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
|               1 |            |        1 |    4 | purchase     | approved        |      1 |
|               2 |            |        4 |    4 | issue        | approved        |      1 |
|               3 |            |        8 |    4 | issue        | approved        |      1 |
|               4 |            |        0 |    4 | verifyIssue  | verifyapproved  |      1 |
|               5 |            |        0 |    4 | verifyIssue  | verifyapproved  |      1 |
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
```

The table includes primary records of purchase & issues if items. order_status = "issue" denotes the item requests & order_status = "verifyIssue" denotes the verifying of that items.

## Desired Output

I need to insert update_stock_id as old_row_id to the table when performing verifyIssue as follows.

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | supplier | user | order_status | transfer_status | status |
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
|               1 |            |        1 |    4 | purchase     | approved        |      1 |
|               2 |            |        4 |    4 | issue        | approved        |      1 |
|               3 |            |        8 |    4 | issue        | approved        |      1 |
|               4 |          2 |        0 |    4 | verifyIssue  | verifyapproved  |      1 |
|               5 |          3 |        0 |    4 | verifyIssue  | verifyapproved  |      1 |
+-----------------+------------+----------+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
```

Controller as follows :

```
public function viewapprovedItemsToIssue($id){
        $this->checkPermissions('index', 'viewapprovedItemsToIssue');
        $bc = array(array('link' => site_url('item/issuingReqFromHD'), 'page' => 'Issuing'),array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Items to Issue'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Items to Issue', 'bc' => $bc);
        $this->data['products'] = $this->Item_model->getProducts();
        $this->data['issueData']=$this->Item_model->ItemRequestfromHDData($id);       
        $this->render('item/viewItemtoIssued', $meta, $this->data);

    }

public function verifyItemReqFromHD()       
    {
        $this->checkPermissions('edit', 'issueApprovedItem');
        $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Item Request From HD'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Item Request From HD', 'bc' => $bc); 

        $this->data['products'] = $this->Item_model->getProducts();                 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item', 'Item', 'required');      

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            $count = count($this->input->post('item_id'));
            $items = $this->input->post('item_id');
            $qts = $this->input->post('qty');           
            $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price'); 

            $usid = $this->input->post('update_stock_id');

            $total = 0;

            for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
                $details[$x]['update_stock_id'] = null;
                $details[$x]['item'] = $items[$x];
                $details[$x]['qty'] = (-1)*$qts[$x];            
                $details[$x]['is_qty'] = $qts[$x]; 
                $details[$x]['unit_price'] = $unit_price[$x];               
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1;               
            }      

            $stock = array(
                'office_id' => '',
                'branch_id' => '',
                'old_row_id' => $usid,              
                'supplier' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                'request_no' => '',
                'auto_no' => '',                
                'purchased_date' => '',
                'billed_date' => '',
                'user' => ucfirst($this->session->userdata('name')),
                'order_status' => 'verifyIssue',
                'transfer_status' => 'Verified',
                'status' => '1'
            );
            //dd($stock);
            if ($this->Item_model->addItemReqFromHD($stock, $details)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Issued..!!');
                redirect('item/approvedItemsToIssue');
            }

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
            $this->render('item/viewItemtoIssued', $meta, $this->data);
        }
    }
```

And the View as follows :

```
<?php
if(!empty($issueData)){
    $common=$issueData[0];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("change", "#item", function () {

        $.ajax({
            'url': '<?=site_url("item/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),
            'method': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {


                var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

                jData.data.forEach(data => {
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + data.item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + data.item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center">' + data.qty + '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  readonly id="unit_price[]" name="unit_price[]" value="' + data.unit_price + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + data.qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                    })
                }

            },
            'error': function () {

            }
        });


    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    var old_row_qty;
    $(document).on("focus", '.rquantity', function () {
        old_row_qty = $(this).val();
    }).on("change", '.rquantity', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var issue_q = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var available_q = parseFloat($(this).data('qty-bal'));

        if (issue_q > available_q) {
            console.log("ssss");
            $(row).addClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', true);
            alert("Can not proceed your request ..!!. Issue quantity is higher than the available quantity..");
        } else {
            console.log("remove");
            $(row).removeClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', false);

        }

    });
</script>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="invoice">
    <!-- title row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> View Items to be Issued
                <small class="pull-right">

                Request No: <b><?=$common->request_no?></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Request Date: <b><?=$common->billed_date?></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;              
                Officer Name: <b><?=$common->username?></b></small>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- Table row -->
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%">
        <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr class="" style="background-color: #33ff99 !important;">
                    <th>Item</th>                   
                    <th class="text-right">Requested Qty</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Approved Qty</th>        
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php

                if (!empty($issueData)) {
                    foreach ($issueData as $rows){

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 40%"><?=$rows->item_name?></td>                           
                            <td style="width: 15%" class="text-right"><?=$rows->r_qty+0?></td>
                            <td style="width: 15%" class="text-right"><?=$rows->ap_qty+0?></td>                          
                        </tr>
                        <?php

                    }
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="box-body" style="display: block">
   <form action="<?= site_url('item/verifyItemReqFromHD') ?>" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Select Item</label>
                            <select name="item" id="item" class="form-control select2" required>
                                <option value="">Select Item</option>
                                <?php
                                if (!empty($products)) {
                                    foreach ($products as $row) {

                                        ?>

                                        <option value="<?= $row->item_id ?>"><?= $row->item_name ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                Stock ID: <b><?=$common->update_stock_id?></b>
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="control-group table-group">
                            <label class="table-label">Issue Items *</label>

                            <div class="controls table-controls">
                                <table id="request_table"
                                       class="table items table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr class="" style="background-color: #ff66a3 !important;">
                                        <th class="col-md-5">Item Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Available Qty</th>                                        
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Unit Price</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Issuing Qty</th>

                                        </th>
                                        <th class="col-md-2" style="width: 30px !important; text-align: center;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr id="tfoot" class="tfoot active">
                                        <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                                        <th class="text-center">0</th>

                                        <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                                                   style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" id="add_sale" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Issue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>  
</div>  
</section>
```

Model as follows :

```
function addItemReqFromHD($data,$details)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        if ($this->db->insert('store_update_stock', $data)) {
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            foreach ($details as $detail) {
                $detail['update_stock_id'] = $id;
                $this->db->insert('store_update_stock_details', $detail);
            }
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;        

    }
```

All the functions working fine & update_stock_id correctly print in my view. But it did not insert as old_row_id through the controller.When I use "dd($stock);" in my controller, the old_row_id IS NULL as follows :

```
Array
(
    [office_id] => 
    [branch_id] => 
    [old_row_id] => 
    [supplier] => 3
    [request_no] => 
    [auto_no] => 
    [purchased_date] => 
    [billed_date] => 
    [user] => Spsstrope1
    [order_status] => verifyIssue
    [transfer_status] => Verified
    [status] => 1
)
```

What may e going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you don't seem to have a input field with the name `update_stock_id`, hence `$usid = $this->input->post('update_stock_id');`is not getting any value, etc... please confirm, thanks

Comment: @ Vickel. That's the issue. But it is not essential. update_stock_id should be inserted as hidden value

Comment: well, then you need to add a hidden input and set its value somewhere somewhen

Comment: @ Vickel. Yes. thats